# PSM with Panel Data

Tags: r, propensity-scores

I have a panel data and I am applying Propensity Score Matching on it. I have multiple treatments (4 treatments). I have estimated the model on the full sample using the CBPS Package. However, I want to perform matching on yearly basis. After extensive search, I could not figure out that how I can do this. Any help in this regard will be much appreciated.

Comment: You can use the Panel Match [package](https://rdrr.io/github/insongkim/PanelMatch/) put together by the same author.